# How can I change the Windows Partition on my iMac?

Tags: windows-7, mac, filesystems, boot-camp

I used Bootcamp to install a Windows XP.
Now I'd like to upgrade to Windows 7, that I already bought.
Problem: The Partition is in FAT32 filesystem....
Can I modify it to NTFS without formatting it?
Is there a way to boot on the Windows 7?
I bought an "Upgrade Pro" from internet, with download link.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess you don't need to change the file system . just upgrade it windows 7 will be take care about file systems

Comment: Actually Windows 7 is giving me a message that it can't install because the HDD is in FAT32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside Windows, you can type `convert /fs:ntfs` from the command line and it'll convert to NTFS.

Comment: I tried it, but it can'T work on the system partition. I'll try again.

Comment: I haven't experienced that problem before in XP. It will prompt to reboot. Perhaps that's what you're speaking of?

Comment: convert /fs:ntfs will work with XP, even on a bootcamp or virtual machine image...  I've done it...  I agree with Randolph...

Comment: Ok, it did work that time, after the reboot! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. Be aware that the allocation unit size by default will be 512 bytes, so you might notice a performance improvement by formatting and installing from scratch at a later stage. Enjoy Windows 7.